# In applescript how do i get two different things to repeat at the same time

Tags: applescript

I am trying to get two different actions to repeat at different intervals but right now only the first action will repeat.

```
repeat
        keystroke "i"
        delay 44
    end repeat
    repeat
        keystroke "o"
        delay 5.5
    end repeat
```

thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could take advantage of the fact that 44 is evenly divisible by 5.5 and use an inner and outer loop:

```
repeat
    keystroke "i"
    repeat 8 times
        keystroke "o"
        delay 5.5
    end repeat
end repeat
```

Note that for the `keystroke` command to work, you need to be in a `tell` block for the `System Events` application.

Comment: haha i love that the numbers just happened to work out so evenly! a perfect solution. And yea I have it in a tell, just didn't paste the entire code block. Thanks again.